How to implement the minimap markers for a custom language in vscode
I would like to be able to define a custom format for the minimap markers within VSCode.
For a custom language we work with comments can only be enclosed within tildas "~", so I have created the marker concept as follows:
~[@Marker = "hello world"]~

Within VSCode I then added the following to the package.json:
"minimap": {
  "markers": [
    {
      "id": "meta.marker.xyz",
      "color": "white",
      "showInMinimap": true
    }
  ]
}

and the following pattern to the language definition:
{
  "name": "meta.marker.xyz",
  "match": "~\\[@Marker\\s*=\\s*\"(.*)\"\\s*\\]~$"
}

I've tested the regex with an online editor, so that shouldn't be the problem.
What else do I need to do to get the hello world to appear within the minimap?

I would try adding them as patternFolding rules (you probably already did this), see https://pieterbranderhorst.github.io/vscode-work/patternfolding/introduction.html#:~:text=vscode-work.%20Pattern%20Folding%20Parameters.  That may be where vscode picks them as markers.

From looking at findSectionHeaders.ts I don't think your form of Marker will work.
The regex that is used to find "Mark"'s in the file is \bMARK:\s*(.*)$.
Which doesn't match your ~[@Marker = "hello world"]~.  And I don't think the regex to match is configurable by an extension in any way.
Can you change to something like ~[@MARK: = "hello world"]~, see Regex101 demo
I think the support for minimap MARK's is quite limited and specific to that regex match at this point.
See Allow the new minimap section headers to use configurable tags - a PR is on the backlog.

Thanks for the response, and sorry for the delayed reply. I had previously seen those GIT comments and misinterpreted them as having been merged into the software - one of the last comments talk about simply setting a configuration value somewhere, which is what I was trying to do... Thank you,
Guess I'll keep on searching for another solution.
